# How to add the following flags to the Visual Studio C++ compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-flags

I need to have these flags in my C/C++ compiler:

> -xc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror

I know how to apply them in CodeBlocks, but I'd rather use VS.

Comment: The Visual C++ compiler uses different flags.

Comment: There is no direct for such metadata and obviously the set of warnings generated will differ between compiler vendors. I believe that something along the lines of `cl /TP /Wall /WX /Ze` should approximate the results in MSVC however.

Comment: -xc == /Fc.  -std, no equivalent, VS2015 already uses C99.  -Wall == /W4.  -Wextra = no equivalent.  -Werror == /WX.  [Just rtfm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for details and equivalent IDE settings.